# Эффективная работа с PCRE

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, pcre

Кто работал с PCRE, подскажите по следующим вопросам:

1. Можно ли передавать в pcre_compile() строку не завершающуюся нулем? Мне приходится специально добавлять нулевой символ. И это явно лишняя операция.
2. Как попросить pcre_compile() не выделять, а использовать ту, которую дам я. Идеальный вариант, pcre_compile() говорит сколько ему нужно памяти, я выдаю.

PCRE практически идеален, но есть вот такие нехорошие моменты.

Comment: И каким же образом вы предлагаете `pcre_compile` определять, где завершается строка, если она не будет завершаться нулем???

Comment: Ну, если отойти от устаревших стереотипов о нулевом символе конце каждой строки и подумать, может прийти гениальная мысль о том, что можно передавать длину строки.

Comment: Для этого понадобится дополнительный параметр функции `pcre_compile`. Возможно, что если "отойти от стереотипов" и очень сильно о нем подумать, то он вдруг откуда ни возьмись появится в функции `pcre_compile`, но я в этом глубоко сомневаюсь. По крайней мере мне подобные трансформации пространства-времени пока не поддаются.

Comment: Этот параметр можно было бы дописать в исходники и даже собрать, но к сожалению я заглянул в код. Там нет длинны в принципе. Функция фигачит пока не наткнется на ноль. В 2015 году я все еще должен следить за нулями в строке. facepalm.

Comment: Вызвать `std::string::c_str()` это же так трудно и накладно, ага.
А строки с завершающим нулем, это не стереотип, а стандарт.

Comment: А причем тут вообще std::string? Этот стандарт давно пора отменить, он сильно устарел. В функции должна передаваться дина строки.

Comment: Этот стандарт можно отменить только если отменить сам язык. Впрочем, миллионы программистов по всему миру не считают такое решение устаревшим, а наоборот, очень даже полезным.  И на то есть веские причины. Что касается памяти, то узнать сколько её понадобится можно только во время компиляции.

Comment: @mikelsv, в pcre2, судя по всему, можно указывать либо флаг на нуль в конце строки, либо размер строки: http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/

Comment: @mikelsv Судя по вопросам, велика вероятность что проект у вас для встроенной системы? Если да, то рекомендую использовать библиотеки специально заточенные под такие задачи. Либо корячить самому с нуля или с готового: избежите много проблем.

Comment: @alexis031182, во, прогресс. я взял пока первую версию, а надо было сразу вторую брать.

Comment: @Cerbo, не, я веб-сервер пишу. Ну так я и беру специально заточенные, взял openssl, pcre, mysql.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не актуален, ТС пытался воспользоваться старой версией библиотеки. В PCRE2 все пожелания уже предсказаны и реализованы.